# Replacing I-frames in h265 stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, h265

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.reddit.com/r/brokenanimegifs/wiki/tutorial

Everything works perfectly. On the basis of this tutorial, I even created my own little tool. It just removes original I-frames and replaces with new one, all works fine with h264 (libx264).

Now I want to repeat this on the basis of x265, as it has a better algorithm for detecting motion and smearing the picture. But unfortunately, nothing works! I tried about such coding options:

```
 ffmpeg -i source.avi -vcodec libx265 -an -bf 0 -x265-params no-pme:subme=1:\
 no-weightp:no-constrained-intra:no-temporal-layers:no-temporal-mvp:no-open-gop:\
 crf=15:bframes=0:radl=0:ctu-info=0:rc-lookahead=0:gop-lookahead=0:\
 lookahead-slices=0:lookahead-threads=0:b-adapt=0:bframe-bias=0:no-b-pyramid:\
 force-flush=1:frame-threads=1 -t 30 -y result.avi
```

But it did not help.

I learned that x265 has many types of I-frames, I suspect that it's all about this. I can replace only the first I-frame in file, it works as before. But I can not change any other I-Frames and get the error in place of replacement, errors like:

```
  [hevc @ 0xb372940] Could not find ref with POC -60:00:09.17 bitrate=62974.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=9.14x    
  [hevc @ 0xb372940] Could not find ref with POC -12:00:20.56 bitrate=62974.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=10.2x
```

Do you think you can repeat this with x265? Here exists any options to force IDR-frames and disable advanced coding techniques?

Comment: Use the last command in this [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23632/1871) to identify HEVC IDR frames and try to alter only those.

Comment: Thanks! I seen this post before, but I have opposite task: find I frames in stream (done at container level), RE-ENCODE this frames, inject in original streams, subsequent frames refer to the coded keyframe and for some reason an error occurs. I understand that the encoded frame, which I substitute, clears the buffer, but it should not be. So I'm looking for a way how to encode each frame sequence (GOP) most independently.

Comment: Yeah, my answer will help you "*find I frames in stream*"  - only the IDR kind. For the remaining  Don't know of a direct option to suppress x265 from generating CRA/BLA frames. It could be a side-effect of some other options.

Comment: Actually I parsing AVI container at byte level. I want to change ANY I-frame, as start every new scene in file. It will be perfect to force IDR-frames at new scenes.

Comment: I think, I-frames in x265 is dependent frames. According to this: http://dustsigns.de/CMS/wp-content/uploads/HEVC.pdf - page 18, I need CRA / BLA / IDR only for frame replacing.

Comment: After seeing some of the examples it wasn't clear why it would be a good idea to do this, usually the result is a mess; then I saw this example: https://i.imgur.com/3Yrajz0.gif where it really worked out great. I think you need to follow the tutorial **exactly**, using a different compressor is unlikely to duplicate the results. I found this Patch to suppress that error message: http://ffmpeg-devel.ffmpeg.narkive.com/7pHRUyTF/patch-avcodec-hevc-refs-silence-could-not-find-ref-with-poc-for-cra-bla - Changing too much is likely to affect whether or not it will even work. Good luck. 